# Edit text in SVG files in android

Tags: android, webview, svg

I have made an SVG file which I'm able to render in the android webview. 
The SVG file also contains text.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arvo";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Arvo"), url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/arvo/v8/J0GYVYTizO1mjpT3aOcSbQ.woff2") format("woff2"), url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/arvo/v8/WJ6D195CfbTRlIs49IbkFw.woff") format("woff");
}
```

```html
<svg width="1280px" height="800px">
  <text id="text1_x5F_left_1_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 18.333 32.96)">
    <tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" y="25.2" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" y="50.4" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" y="75.6" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">D</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I want to edit the text during runtime. I also have a JavaScript that works on iPhone, but not on android. How do I edit it?

EDIT: I'm using [this](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android) library and this patch to parse text tag in SVG.
[Enable text parsing in svg patch](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/issues/attachmentText?id=20&aid=200000000&name=enableText.patch&token=QICiCxYTECcEyM3_Id65MkfdjN8:1352200670131)

I'm not really sure how to use it. Right now the SVG is rendered and the example text that was on the SVG is gone. If I want to add text to it, how should it be done.

Comment: Do you wan to change it during runtime with the android java, or javascript is also acceptable ?

Comment: maybe adding the javascript that works on iOS could help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested on movile devices, but you can make any portion of your document editable by adding the HTML5 tag `contenteditable`, even the svg's text previously declared.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arvo";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Arvo"), url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/arvo/v8/J0GYVYTizO1mjpT3aOcSbQ.woff2") format("woff2"), url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/arvo/v8/WJ6D195CfbTRlIs49IbkFw.woff") format("woff");
}
#editable {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
  <svg width="1280px" height="800px">
    <text id="text1_x5F_left_1_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 18.333 32.96)">
      <tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="25.2" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="50.4" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" y="75.6" font-family="'Arvo'" font-size="21">D</tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

As far as I know, you can insert HTML ( and perhaps custom tags), but I'm not pretty sure so.. please refer to [Document.execComand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) function and watch for the `formatBlock` description in case you need not only to edit the existing svg's elements, but to add new elements.

UPDATE: Even if I can't test it directly from a webview inside a custom app I tested on a Sphere tab in the default android browser.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That still leaves the question of how to get from code that runs in the normal code execution environment of android into what happens inside the webview.

Comment: Well... if it runs on the default browser it should run on an android view isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript in your webview to modify the `svg` content from android java code.
as described [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-inject-javascript-into-an-android-web-view-for-a-more-dynamic-ux/)

```java
String newText="new text 1";
String javascript="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("tspan")[0].innerHTML='"+newText+"';"
webView.loadUrl(javascript);

String newText="new text 2";
String javascript="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1].innerHTML='"+newText+"';"
webView.loadUrl(javascript);

...

String newText="new text 4";
String javascript="javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("tspan")[3].innerHTML='"+newText+"';"
webView.loadUrl(javascript);
```

You have, of course to properly escape the java string you need to insert in your javascript (replacing `"` with `\"` for example).

Answer (score -1):

I used this code to change the content of svg text on the fly using javascript.

//**********In Javascript

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var  text = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");    

text.setAttribute("x", x_cooridnates);
text.setAttribute("y", y_cooridnates);    

text.textContent = 'Dynamic Content'; //You can add any text you want 

document.getElementById("text_group").appendChild(text);
```

//**********In the html body section

```
<svg width="1280px" height="800px">
        <g id="text_group" fill="#000000" ></g>
</svg>
```

Hope this is the out put you want.